# Setting up a model in magento 1.5.x

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I can successfully do getModel(module/licenses) but then when I load($id) things break.

My database table is setup fine called licenses.

my config file has in the global -> modules tag

```xml
<modulename>
  <class>NameSpace_Module_Model></class>
  <resourceModel>module_mysql4</resourceModel>
</modulename>
<modulename_mysql4>
  <class>NameSpace_Module_Model_Mysql4</class>
  <entities>
    <licenses>
      <table>licenses</table>
    </licenses>
  </entities>
</modulename_mysql4>
```

I then have a file located at my module at Model/Licenses.php which has the class `NameSpace_Module_Model_Licenses extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` and includes a construc function which does `$this->_init('module/licenses')`

I also have a file in my module at Model/Mysql4/Licenses.php with the class `NameSpace_Module_Model_Mysql4_Model_Licenses extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract` with a constructor which does `$this->_init('module/licenses', 'primary key here')` This class never seems to be instantiated because I've added a var_dump exit that never seems to run

So I can get my model and dump it onto the screen but if I do a load($id) things die without warning in any log files.  If I run it in a try catch i still get nothing. If I run a ->getResource() instead in a try catch and dump out the exception it gives a message that 
    Mage registry key "_resource_singleton/module/licenses" already exists.

So how does one properly setup a model for a table?

Comment: Turns out that I had duplicated part of my config.xml model declaration in another module's config file. All is working

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

> Mage registry key "_resource_singleton/module/licenses" already exists

is always an indication is that you've duped a resourceModel config node.